# Text with hyperlink returns "\xa0" when extracting text from a word file (python-docx)

Tags: python, python-docx

I've been trying to extract text from a word file using `python-docx`

Sample text:
[image: The text "artificial intelligence (AI)" contains a hyperlink.']
(where the text "artificial intelligence (AI)" contains a hyperlink)

To get this text, I did this:

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document(filename)

rawdata = []

for par in doc.paragraphs:
  rawdata.append(par.text)

print(rawdata)
```

However, this returned something like this:

```
['What is machine learning?', 'Machine learning is a branch of\xa0\xa0and computer science which focuses on the use of data and algorithms to imitate the way that humans learn, gradually improving its accuracy.'...
```

Here, the text "artificial intelligence (AI)" became '\xa0\xa0' which is what I don't want.

I'm still new to python and tried to do some digging and found that \xa0 is a non-breaking space... (what does this have to do with a link?)

So question: how do I get the original text which contained a hyperlink using python-docx?

(Edit: I'm not trying to remove '\xa0' from a string, the original text is what I need)

The original goal:
Unlink all links from the word file through python but still keep the text in-tact.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @scanny I did try to look that up beforehand and found a way to collect all hyperlinks and it worked. However, the text with that exact hyperlink when printed on my terminal returned "\xa0\xa0" which is primarily the issue here..

Comment: I'm not getting your question. `python-docx` has no API support for including hyperlink text in `paragraph.text`. If you've found a way to do that, great. `\xa0` is a legitimate character that can appear in text and I expect it appears exactly where this indicates, the space before "artificial" and the space after "(AI)" are both non-breaking spaces. If you don't like that then change them to something else. If you clarify your question I'll see if I can help but I don't get specifically what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

\xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 ([ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)), also chr(160).

You can replace it with a space with **unicode.normalize**

```py
    import unicodedata

    text = "Machine learning is a branch of\xa0\xa0and computer science..."
    text =  unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", text)
```

You can use NFKD, NFC and NFD parameters, more info [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/uc/nfc_vs_nfd.html)

For your specific case:

```py
    import unicodedata
    from docx import Document
    
    doc = Document(filename)
    
    rawdata = []
    
    for par in doc.paragraphs:
      rawdata.append(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", par.text))
    
    print(rawdata)
```

should work

Comment: Although this is true, it doesn't relate to his problem in any way.

Comment: I think you've missed the whole point.  The problem is he is getting `"\xa0\xa0"` where he is expecting to find a hyperlink.  He doesn't WANT non-breaking spaces, and this is NOT an issue of character translation.  This is a Word-specific issue, that there is a marker where there should be a hytperlink.